# Converting JavaScript Array.slice + implicit extension to C++ vector

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays

I am porting a JavaScript code to C++ .

Pseudo code :

> if n = 1 then APPEND(orders, order)

JavaScript(order and orders are arrays)  :

```
var order = new array();
var orders = new array();
//....
if (n == 1)
{
    orders[orders.length] = order.slice(); // append copy
}
```

I am using vectors instead of array in C++ .
The C++ code i think should be just :

```
vector<int> order;
vector<vector<int> > orders;
//.....
orders.push_back(order)
```

Is this code correct for the above psudeo and javascript code ?

Comment: is `order` an array too ? your C++ code doesn't say anything regarding that `order.slice()`. also `slice()` takes two arguments. you have none. which doesn't clarify your intension. your don't need `orders.length` too. even in javascript there is array.push() method

Comment: I have edited the question , and what slice does is it copies the whole array when arguments are not there . And i have the psuedo code and javascript, the given javascript is the correct implementation of the pseudo code , i need to convert them to C++ .

Comment: If you are copying the whole array there there is nothing `slicing` here. it is cloning instead. do you really need a deep copy ? In your C++ implementation You have left the cloning part unimplemented

Comment: yup , orders is becoming a 2D array dynamically and order is getting copied in it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a condition `n == 1` I don't know why you have skipped that in your C++ implementation.
in comments you said you are using `slice()` to make a copy of original list so you do also need to do the same in your C++ implementation.

```
vector< vector<int> > orders;
vector<int> order;
//and to clone and append
std::vector cloned;
std::copy(order.begin(), order.end(), std::back_inserter(cloned));
if(n == 1)
   orders.push_back(cloned);
```

Comment: The n==1 condition is also there is c++ , sorry forgot to add it . but why do i need to make a clone ? i am only concerned with the final contents of orders .  Does the final value of orders in your code and my code will be same ?

Comment: You said in comments that you are using `slice` to make a copy

Comment: I haven't written the code , i am just porting it to C++ . I told you that because that is the purpose of slice function without arguments . i want to ask if the value of orders will be same if i use this c++ code instead of javascript.

Comment: Then why do you need to call `slice()` even ? you are neither slicing a range nor do you want to make a copy . and yes if you don't need a copy then just do `orders.push_back(order)` that will be file